# How to make change on Apache/Nginx webserver using php or python script

Tags: php, python, apache, nginx, directadmin

Im programming `php` and `python` for website and I need a way to modify apache/nginx settings to add some subdomain and/or addon-domain to the server.
Is it possible to do this things? Does affect DirectAdmin settings?
Is it possible to do it using DirectAdmin scripts?

Thanks in advance.